# Search Excel sheet for specific value and return corresponding cell value with python

Tags: python

I have an Excel file. I need to search only column "A" in the Excel sheet until it matches a text string. When the script finds that match, I would like to see the corresponding cell value. Thanks for your helps in advance!

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the xlrd library, and iterate through the rows.

```py
import xlrd 

filepath = r'C:\Desktop\example.xlsx'
textstring = "foo"
wb = xlrd.openworkbook(filepath)
ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for row in range(ws.nrows):
     target = str(ws.cell(row, 0).value)
     if target == textstring:
          print(target)
          print(row)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.
but I got this error
NameError: name 'nrows' is not defined

Comment: Apologies - I forgot to actually import the excel sheet as an object (so I couldn't use the nrows or cell methods). I've edited the code. Let me know if it works!